# How to one-hot encode a vector with arbitrary number of unique values?

Tags: numpy, one-hot-encoding

Given a output vector `y` that can have any number of discrete values, say from the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. Let the vector have this instance:

```
y = [1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Is there a numpy-tonic library way of generating a one-hot encoded representation of this vector? I.e. such that

```
y_enc =
y1 y2 y3 y4
1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  0  1
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0
```

For the case {0, 1} i have a small example but I cant see this going in the right direction:

```
>>> k
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [1.]])
>>> z = np.zeros((5,2))
>>> z
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
>>> for i,ki in enumerate(k):
...   if (ki == 0):
...     z[i][0] += 1
...   if (ki == 1):
...     z[i][1] += 1
... 
>>> z
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
>>>
```

Comment: Here is a solution with a loop: `np.hstack([y[:,None]==i for i in range(np.min(y), np.max(y)+1)]).astype(np.int32)`

Answer (score 1):

I find it most convenient by creating an identity matrix and indexing it with `y` by using "fancy indexing"

```
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1])
one_hot = np.eye(5, dtype=np.int32)[y]
```

Now `one_hot` will be

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

And since you are not using the value `0` you could slice away the first column by doing

```
one_hot[:,1:]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, based on [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the option `return_inverse=True`:

```
In [67]: def onehot(a):
    ...:     u, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    ...:     n = len(a)
    ...:     result = np.zeros((n, len(u)), dtype=int)
    ...:     result[np.arange(n), inv] = 1
    ...:     return u, result
    ...: 

In [68]: y = [1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1]

In [69]: values, encoded = onehot(y)

In [70]: values
Out[70]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [71]: encoded
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```